# Set BoxCollider size to GameObject size programatically

Tags: unity-game-engine

i create an gameobject in runtime and then add it a `BoxCollider2d` Component like below:

```
GameObject card = new GameObject("card");
card.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
card.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>.size = new Vector2(?);
```

in new vector2(?) i need a value that make box collider size exact same as card object size. the card has sprite so i try this :

```
 card.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
 card.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite
```

so i try like this ?

```
int cardWidth = (int)card.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.rect.width;
int cardHeight = (int)card.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.rect.height;
```

and then :

```
card.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = new Vector2(cardWidth, cardHeight);
```

this is my way i want to set size of collider to exact same as card object but it doesn't work. so please show me a way that i can set size of box collider same as card object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i find the solution . the with and height of each sprit is 256px and my unit is 128 so `256/128=2` now my vector2 size is :

```
card.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>.size = new Vector2(2,2);
```

and it's exact same as object size